# Data area loads differently in interactive and submit jobs in as400

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am reading a data area in interactive and submit jobs. Turkish characters in the data area are loading properly in submit job where as in the interactive job, they are converting to junk. 
The job ccsid is same for both interactive and submit job.
What could be the issue?

Comment: Is the same program(s) writing and reading the data area in both cases?  Show the code... show the Language, Country, CCSID, Default CCSID from DSPJOB  for both interactive & batch...

Comment: For interactive jobs(During login), data area loading is happening with 297 CCSID and after loading the data area, they are changing the job CCSID to 1026. Whereas the batch job is loading with the turkish (1026) CCSID. So, the turkish characters are converting to junk in interactive job.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using RPG, then RPG only checks the job CCSID during module initialization. If you change the job CCSID while the program is running, RPG won't know about the change. "Module initialization" happens when the first procedure in a module is called, and then it happens again if a program is called after it ended the previous call with LR on.

So, if RPG is involved, you should change the job CCSID before you call the RPG program.